Icecast2 with ssl on windows Mountpoint disappears
When I activate SSL in the latest version IceCast2, my mountpoint disappears. I can open the admin with https. But the stream (mountpoint)is gone. Also on the admin page it no longer appears under Active Mountpoints. I have the configuration below.
<icecast>
  <location>Earth</location>
  <admin>icemaster@localhost</admin>

  <limits>
    <clients>100</clients>
    <sources>6</sources>
    <threadpool>6</threadpool>
    <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
    <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
    <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
    <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
    <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
    <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
  </limits>

  <authentication>
    <source-password>xxx</source-password>
    <relay-password>xxx</relay-password>
    <admin-user>xxx</admin-user>
    <admin-password>xxx</admin-password>
  </authentication>


  <listen-socket>
    <bind-address>137.34.x.x</bind-address>
    <port>443</port>
    <ssl>1</ssl>
  </listen-socket>

  <mount>
    <mount-name>/128</mount-name>
    <max-listeners>250</max-listeners>
    <hidden>1</hidden>
    <no-yp>1</no-yp>
  </mount>

  <fileserve>1</fileserve>

  <paths>
    <basedir>C:\Icecast2\443</basedir>
    <logdir>C:\Icecast2\443\log</logdir>
    <webroot>C:\Icecast2\443\web</webroot>
    <adminroot>C:\Icecast2\admin</adminroot>
    <ssl-certificate>C:\Icecast2\certificate\streaming-servers.nl.pem</ssl-certificate>
    <ssl-allowed-ciphers>ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS</ssl-allowed-ciphers>
    <alias source="/" dest="/status.xsl"/>
  </paths>

  <logging>
    <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
    <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
    <loglevel>4</loglevel> <!-- 4 Debug, 3 Info, 2 Warn, 1 Error -->
  </logging>

  <security>
    <chroot>0</chroot>
  </security>
</icecast>

What mis I to activate SSL?
